# Get a variable in CaretListener (like getActionCommand)

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtextfield

I want to pass a variable into a CaretListener when my JTextFiled is update.

My listener work perfectly thanks to "caretUpdate".

However, I don't know how to pass a variable to my "caretUpdate", like "e.getActionCommand()" when I used "actionPerformed" but it's seem to not exist for "caretUpdate", is there a solution ?

Edit : 
In My view I have a textField witch is attach to a listener :

```
textField.setActionCommand("test");
textField.addCaretListener(this.controller);
```

In My controller I have the listener, and I want to get the value "test" :

```
public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
    // here I want to get the "test" value
    String maVar = e.getActionCommand();
}
```

But e.getActionCommand() doesn't exist for CaretEvent. Is there an alternative ?

Comment: Maybe you could show some code

Comment: Yes thanks I have changed that.

Comment: I disagree with @SimonMartinelli. Showing 'some code' usually results in either a code dump (too long) or uncompilable code snippets as seen above. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).